# Extract one sentence from an EventLog message

Tags: regex, powershell, event-log

Trying to read only a fraction of the message in a series of events. Having trouble getting good output.

My Script (assume that all variables are properly setup, I'm able to gather the correct events, etc.):

```
$Events = Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $Server -FilterHashtable @{LogName=$LogName;
StartTime=$StartTime} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
| Where-Object {$_.message -match "$Keyword1|$Keyword2"}

foreach ($Event in $Events)
{

    $InStuff = $Event.Message            

    $InStuff = $InStuff.Split("`n").Trim("`r")
    $Null = $InStuff.Where({$_ -match '<Message>(?<EventMessage>.+)</Message>'})
    $EventMessage = $Matches.EventMessage
    $Null = $InStuff.Where({$_ -match '\[Key\] : (?<EventKey>.+)'})
    $EventKey = $Matches.EventKey

    $EventXML = [xml]$Event.ToXml()
    $EventArray = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{

    EventID = $Event.Id
    EventTime = $Event.TimeCreated
    EventProvider = $Event.ProviderName
    EventLog = $Event.LogName
    EventMessage = $EventMessage
    EventKey = $EventKey
    }

    $EventArray | Select EventTime,EventLog,EventProvider,EventID,EventMessage,EventKey
}
```

Result (notice, EventMessage is empty):

```
EventTime     : 7/30/2018 3:43:54 PM
EventLog      : CCS
EventProvider : CCS Logging
EventID       : 100
EventMessage  : 
EventKey      : R-MD
```

However...if in my script I do this (manually paste an excerpt from a log):

```
$InStuff = @'
Timestamp: 7/30/2018 3:43:54 PM
    Message: <Description>An exception has been detected.</Description>
        <DateTime>2018-07-30 11:43:54Z</DateTime>
        <Message>Exception Message:No category found for key = R-MD.</Message>
    [Key] : R-MD
    [LocaleId] : 1033
'@
```

Instead of this:

```
$InStuff = $Event.Message
```

Then I get a good result:

```
EventTime     : 7/30/2018 3:43:54 PM
EventLog      : CCS
EventProvider : CCS Logging
EventID       : 100
EventMessage  : Exception Message:No category found for key = R-MD.
EventKey      : R-MD
```

If it helps, `$Event.Message.GetType()` & `$Event.Message[0].GetType()` yields the following:

```
True | True | String | System.Object
True | True | Char | System.ValueType
```

Basically, to recap, I need:

1. Whatever is in between the `<Message>` and `</Message>` tags of `$Event.Message`
2. Whatever the value is (be it a sentence or 3-4 characters) of `[Key] :`

Both of these things seem to reside inside of `$Event.Message`.

My actual logs have multiple different things that could be in there so particularly targeting X characters for splitting, etc. isn't an option and what I've managed so far is the help of some posters on Reddit or the internet in general. I've tried various RegEx combo's I've found to no avail and I can't seem to wrap my head around how to use RegEx.

I've spent the better part of 12hrs just trying to get his output correct...I'm at a loss.

Please help!

=====================

EDIT: Below is the exported event, per request:

```
<Objs Version="1.1.0.1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04">
  <Obj RefId="0">
    <TN RefId="0">
      <T>System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord</T>
      <T>System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventRecord</T>
      <T>System.Object</T>
    </TN>
    <ToString>System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord</ToString>
    <Props>
      <I32 N="Id">100</I32>
      <Nil N="Version" />
      <I32 N="Qualifiers">0</I32>
      <By N="Level">4</By>
      <I32 N="Task">0</I32>
      <Nil N="Opcode" />
      <I64 N="Keywords">36028797018963968</I64>
      <I64 N="RecordId">4824</I64>
      <S N="ProviderName">CCS LOGGING</S>
      <Nil N="ProviderId" />
      <S N="LogName">CCS</S>
      <Nil N="ProcessId" />
      <Nil N="ThreadId" />
      <S N="MachineName">Test</S>
      <Nil N="UserId" />
      <DT N="TimeCreated">2018-08-03T11:57:53-04:00</DT>
      <Nil N="ActivityId" />
      <Nil N="RelatedActivityId" />
      <S N="ContainerLog">ccs</S>
      <Obj N="MatchedQueryIds" RefId="1">
        <TN RefId="1">
          <T>System.UInt32[]</T>
          <T>System.Array</T>
          <T>System.Object</T>
        </TN>
        <LST />
      </Obj>
      <Obj N="Bookmark" RefId="2">
        <TN RefId="2">
          <T>System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventBookmark</T>
          <T>System.Object</T>
        </TN>
        <ToString>System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventBookmark</ToString>
      </Obj>
      <S N="LevelDisplayName">Information</S>
      <S N="OpcodeDisplayName">Info</S>
      <Nil N="TaskDisplayName" />
      <Obj N="KeywordsDisplayNames" RefId="3">
        <TN RefId="3">
          <T>System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]</T>
          <T>System.Object</T>
        </TN>
        <LST>
          <S>Classic</S>
        </LST>
      </Obj>
      <Obj N="Properties" RefId="4">
        <TN RefId="4">
          <T>System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventProperty, System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]</T>
          <T>System.Object</T>
        </TN>
        <LST>
          <Obj RefId="5">
            <TN RefId="5">
              <T>System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventProperty</T>
              <T>System.Object</T>
            </TN>
            <ToString>System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventProperty</ToString>
            <Props>
              <S N="Value">Timestamp: 8/3/2018 3:57:53 PM_x000D__x000A_Message: &lt;Exception handlingInstanceId="7bdbceed-ef96-4f0d-985a-88f7c8641661"&gt;_x000D__x000A_  &lt;DateTime&gt;2018-08-03 11:57:53Z&lt;/DateTime&gt;_x000D__x000A_  &lt;Message&gt;Exception Message Key:RDKEYNF_x000D__x000A_Exception Message:No record found in ApplicationLabels category for key = R-MD, Locale = 1033, Filter = Active, and EffectiveDate = 8/3/2018.&lt;/Message&gt;_x000D__x000A_  &lt;Source&gt;AFS&lt;/Source&gt;_x000D__x000A_  &lt;HelpLink /&gt;_x000D__x000A_  &lt;Property name="Parameters"&gt;_x000D__x000A_[CategoryName] : ApplicationLabels_x000D__x000A_[Key] : R-MD_x000D__x000A_[LocaleId] : 1033_x000D__x000A_</S>
            </Props>
          </Obj>
        </LST>
      </Obj>
    </Props>
    <MS>
      <S N="Message">Timestamp: 8/3/2018 3:57:53 PM_x000D__x000A_Message: &lt;Exception handlingInstanceId="7bdbceed-ef96-4f0d-985a-88f7c8641661"&gt;_x000D__x000A_  &lt;DateTime&gt;2018-08-03 11:57:53Z&lt;/DateTime&gt;_x000D__x000A_  &lt;Message&gt;Exception Message Key:RDKEYNF_x000D__x000A_Exception Message:No record found in ApplicationLabels category for key = R-MD, Locale = 1033, Filter = Active, and EffectiveDate = 8/3/2018.&lt;/Message&gt;_x000D__x000A_  &lt;Source&gt;AFS&lt;/Source&gt;_x000D__x000A_  &lt;HelpLink /&gt;_x000D__x000A_  &lt;Property name="Parameters"&gt;_x000D__x000A_[CategoryName] : ApplicationLabels_x000D__x000A_[Key] : R-MD_x000D__x000A_[LocaleId] : 1033_x000D__x000A_</S>
    </MS>
  </Obj>
</Objs>
```

Comment: Could you export your test event with `Export-CliXml` and add it to your question?  That way people can import it and help.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 is there a way to edit it slightly? There is some customer data (company name, etc.) in the entries, etc. That's my only issue, otherwise I'll absolutely do it.

Comment: You should be able just to edit the resulting XML to sanitize it as long as the type information stays intact.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1, I've added the exported test even to my question. Will this suffice or would you prefer I use something else to share it? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running this one liner got me the value between `<Message></Message>` from $InStuff:

```
[regex]::matches($InStuff,'<Message>(.*?)<\/Message>').value.Replace("<Message>","")
.Replace("</Message>","").Trim()
```

Output:

```
Exception Message:No category found for key = R-MD.
```

For the [Key] value:

```
[regex]::matches($InStuff,'(?<=\[Key\]).*').value.Replace(":","").Trim()
```

Output:

```
R-MD
```

A good website to learn about regex is: https://regex101.com/, they explain what each part of your regex is doing on the test string.

Comment: Thanks @Sohvax! Message seems to be working now! However, Key is taking the rest of the message (including stuff I sanitized out). Is there a way to make it stop at [LocaleId]? I tried basically using the message one and changing <Message> to [Key] and </Message> to [LocaleId] but I'm probably missing a couple of other regex combos there...I tried using that site this weekend and wasn't quite able to wrap my head around the principle or what not...

Comment: Okay, I got it down to showing my the Key code but it includes [LocaleId] at the end using the following RegEx and messing with that calculator. Can't seem to get it to stop just before the `[` of the LocaleId.

`(?<=\[Key\]).*(\[LocaleId\])`

Comment: After some more playing around, I think I got it...seems to be working. I used the following: `EventKey = [regex]::matches($MessageContents,'(?<=\[Key\]).*(\[LocaleId\])').Value.Replace(":","").Replace("[LocaleId]","").Trim()`. Thanks Sohvax for setting me down the path!

Comment: @Ilya Sorry for the late reply, good to see you've got it working! Glad it helped!

Comment: I actually could still use a little help. I guess not all of my logs have `[Key]` followed by `[LocaleId]`, some have no `LocaleId` but have like `[Filter]` instead...how do I get it to give me the key but then stop at the first `[`] it sees?

Comment: You could make the regex stop at the first opening bracket it sees. So instead of taking the complete tag [LocaleId], you can go for:
`(?<=\[Key\]).*(?=\[)`

Comment: Hmm...that checked out in the regex calculator but when I ran it on a live server it removed `[LocalId]` but then kept on printing everything past that... @Sohvax